# In Python, why does this line run from the file (without exception), but throw an exception when run in the shell?

Tags: python, shell, dictionary

I was going through Peter Norvig's Sudoku solver code (http://norvig.com/sudopy.shtml) and came across this line:

```
peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s],[]))-set([s]))
         for s in squares)
```

If I copy the code up to and including this line (i.e. up to line 28), and run it from a file, it runs fine, and the dictionary 'peers' has the excepted values. However, if after I run this file, I try and run this line from the shell, I get an error:

```
peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s],[]))-set([s]))
             for s in squares)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-2652de1ecd8a> in <module>()
      1 peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s],[]))-set([s]))
----> 2              for s in squares)

<ipython-input-33-2652de1ecd8a> in <genexpr>((s,))
      1 peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s],[]))-set([s]))
----> 2              for s in squares)

C:\PyCanopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.pyc in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   1717         except AttributeError:
   1718             return _methods._sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 1719                                 out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
   1720         # NOTE: Dropping the keepdims parameters here...
   1721         return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)

C:\PyCanopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.pyc in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     30 
     31 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 32     return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     33 
     34 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I haven't been able to work out why this is. I found this line of code strange to begin with, since it has a `sum` over values of a `dict` key plus an empty `[]`. Any guidance? Thanks.

Comment: I can't help with your main question, but the 2nd arg to Python's built-in `sum` function is the starting value, which is zero by default. By supplying `[]` as the start arg it lets you flatten a list of lists to a single list. Eg, `sum([[1],[2],[3]],[])` evaluates to `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works for me both in `python` interpreter and `ipython`.
It looks like before running the code you did this:

```
from numpy import sum
```

So now `sum` is not python's standard `sum`, but it is a different function imported from `numpy`.
This is why the code raises an error.

Solution: just exit from `ipython` shell, run it again and paste the code into it.

**Edit**: regarding the sum with empty list, it is just a trick to make the units[s] flat.
For example, the units['I1'] looks like this:

```
[['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1', 'G1', 'H1', 'I1'],
 ['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6', 'I7', 'I8', 'I9'],
 ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'I1', 'I2', 'I3']]
```

And the `sum(units['I1'], [])` looks like this:

```
['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1', 'G1', 'H1', 'I1', 'I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I6', 'I7', 'I8', 'I9', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'I1', 'I2', 'I3']
```

What the sum does under the hood is something like this:

```
list = []
for elem in units['I1']:
    list = list + elem
```

Comment: huh. how about that... i can see this might be the case, although i'm struggling to test it right now. I can't seem to figure out why Canopy's interpreter automatically loads numpy, nor how to turn it off. Thanks!

Comment: @nevakanezzar You are welcome. I also updated the answer with explanation about what sum(units[s], []) does.